# android - Grabbing collectionGroups in a query returning empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on using a [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query and trying to pass it to a Recyclerview but it seems to always be coming up empty.

Firstly, my understanding is that collectionGroups used not to be so great but now I hear it's fixed and it allows a query to grab all documents under a collectionGroup name.

The query I show below doesn't grab anything and I can't figure out why. From the explanation in the documentation, it should be able to grab all bookPendingRequests items across all books(the parent Items) that have an owner of whoever is logged in.

```
String mAuthUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
```

the line above allows me to grab the logged in username

```
Query query = firestoreDB.collectionGroup("bookPendingRequests").whereEqualTo("mOwner", mAuthUser)
```

This line above is what i imagine should work.

**code**

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BookRequestModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<BookRequestModel>()
                .setQuery(query, BookRequestModel.class)
                .build();

        mBookRequestsAdapter = new BookRequestsAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView bookRequestListRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.bookRequestListRecyclerViewId);
        bookRequestListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        bookRequestListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        bookRequestListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mBookRequestsAdapter);
```

here's an image of what it looks link in firebase:

[image]

here's an image of my index for the collectionGroup
[image]

Right now I'm just trying to get the query to actually grab the "bookPendingRequests".

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: try to log the value of "mAuthUser". make sure it is euqal to "username2"

Comment: Have you tried to use a hardcoded value, as Har Kal mentioned in his comment? Does it work that way?  Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @HarKal and @AlexMamo the logged-in username is "username2". mAuthUser is equal to "username2" when I debug so that one is okay. I just tried ```query.get()```(queryDocumentSnapshots), and it starts returning values to me. I'll start investigating that and seeing if I can pass that my recycler view unless you guys have other ideas to check out.

Comment: have u added the rules version 2 in firestore rules 

Comment: i dont remember the exact syntax but some version kind of thing has been added to the firestore rules. make sure u have put it in firestore rules. and for now open read write to everything. try and comment back 

Comment: @HarKal just checked it. I don't remember ever changing to version 2 but that's what it is. ```rules_version = '2';```

Comment: did u try with default database rules ?

Comment: @HarKal I just reset the rules and got the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexMamo and @HarKal, I updated my code to give more context to the issue. it still has an output of 0 even with the updated rules. When I look at my other code for reference, the query checks against a collection reference which has an output of the desired amount. The issue seems to be isolated to CollectionGroups. As mentioned before, the ```query.get()``` returns the values but puts everything in querySnapshots.

Comment: go and tweet about it to => https://twitter.com/puf he ll help u for sure